# regex: not followed by

Tags: regex, linux, shell

I need to check if in a log file I have one text eg `server crashed` that is **not** followed by other text `server is up again` (because if I find such case that means I have to start the server manually). Of course, between those texts there may be many different lines. I want to use any simple linux command line tool, eg. pcregrep but I failed to create a regex

Comment: 1. Please post what you've tried so far, including your code/script. 2. It would be hard for someone to answer this question without knowing exactly what your server log looks like, you need to provide examples. 3. Server administration questions belong at serverfault.com.

Comment: it's not a server question. it's a regex question. server is just an example to make it clear. i tried: `pcregrep -M 'server crashed(\n|.)*(?!.*server is up again)' logfile.log`

Comment: Server command help is still something that belongs on http://serverfault.com/. Those guys know Regex just as much as we do, believe me.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just try to connect to the server, and if you can't, investigate whether it's down? I can think of quite a few reasons a server might be down, but the notifications didn't make it into some logfile somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for any line matching either of the two lines, then only look at the last one:

```
 grep "server crashed\|server is up again" | tail -n 1
```

or

```
 # Use extended regular expressions, which treat | as an operator without escaping it
 grep -E "server crashed|server is up again" | tail -n 1
```

or

```
 # Use egrep, a synonym for grep -E
 egrep "server crashed|server is up again" | tail -n 1
```

If the output contains "server crashed", you need to restart the server. If the output contains "server is up again", it is still running and you needn't do anything.

Comment: i think, to include the edge case, it should be 'If the output contains "server crashed", you need to restart the server. otherwise it's still running'. but basically this solves the problem even without complicated regex. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I like awk for simple state machines like this

```
awk '
    /server crashed/ {is_crashed=1}
    is_crashed && /server is up again/ {is_up_again=1; exit}
    END {
        if (! is_up_again) {
            print "Oops, crashed and NOT up again"
            exit 1
        }
    }
' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Perl's reggex with negative lookahead assertions (not sure if your grep does it)

```
$ cat check.pl
$/=""; 
my $line = <>; 
$line =~ /(server crashed)(?!.+server is up again)/sg; 
print "$1\n";

$ perl check.pl < file_with_crash
server crashed

$ perl check.pl < file_with_crash_and_restart
$ # Nada
```

Comment: GNU grep with `-P` should handle that.

Answer (score 0):

here is something you can do with awk - it is reversing the order but it works - you can do what you like when you get a result:

```
    cat file1.txt 
server crashed
a
server is up again
b
c
d
server crashed
server is up again
```

so the lines are now joined with 2nd echoed before first:

```
awk '!(NR%2){print$0p}{p=$0}' file1.txt 
aserver crashed
bserver is up again
dc
server is up againserver crashed
```

Now to get it to only return : server is up againserver crashed

```
 awk '!(NR%2){if ($0p ~ "server is up againserver crashed") {print p$0 } }{p=$0} ' file1.txt
server crashedserver is up again
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command will give a single-line output beginning with the line number where the last server crash occurred:

```
grep -n 'server crashed' server.log | tail -n 1
```

Then do the same for `server is up again`, and compare the line numbers.